# How to prevent the ComboBox from automatically changing the SelectedText on Font change at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does anyone know why if you change the font of a ComboBox (.NET) at runtime, the SelectedText is also automatically changed and the text is then automatically highlighted?

[image]

It may seem trivial, but we are managing massive automatic runtime resizes on multiple features, and this specific behavior of the ComboBox causes us problems.
With all other .NET controls so far we have not encountered this problem.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to avoid this behavior?
For example some property on the control.

Sure, you can subscribe to some events and reset each time, but we don't want to be forced to code hundreds of forms.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT: I specify that the problem is that the text is HIGHLIGHTED: for some reason the SelectedText is set. This causes problems for us, we would like it to simply zoom the control and text without any highlighting, like all other WindowsForm controls do.

Comment: Are you saying that this behavior doesn't apply to for example the `TextBox`, `DTP` controls as well? No, it does. The control needs to resize itself to fit the new Font. Grows or shrinks depending on the new Font's glyphs and size. Back to the `ComboBox`. If you mean here changing the Font of the dropdown, then you need to draw the items yourself. The steps are: 1) `DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;` 2) Handle `MeasureItem` to set a proper `e.ItemHeight`. 3) Handle `DrawItem` to draw the items using that new Font.

Comment: No, the problem isn't that the control gets bigger. In fact, we really want control to scale.
The problem is that for some reason changing the font at runtime highlights the entire text written in the combo box. Unfortunately this behavior creates graphical problems for other managements.
Yes, I confirm that only the ComboBox has this behavior: if I change the Font of a TextBox at runtime, the text shown in the TextBox is not highlighted.

Comment: You had to mention that in your original post. _Highlight_ and _Change_ means different things.

Comment: "changing the SelectedText" of a ComboBox is equivalent to "highlighting", because the SelectedText property takes care exactly of highlighting the text.
However, I had already edited the post to make the question even clearer, in fact I got an answer. Thank you

Comment: Very well. Congratulation and good for you son.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems an interesting behavior of Combobox. Not sure why it is happening. But I found 2 workarounds for this issue

1. Change the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`. It works but we can't input any text to the combobox
2. Change the `AutoCompleteMode` to any other values other than `None` (i.e. `Suggest`, `Append` or `SuggestAppend`)

Comment: Thank you so much for these valuable hints!
We research how to adapt them to our needs.